# Python says I have an indented block when I don't?

Tags: python

```
def cave(): 
    global key
    global response
    print(''' You find yourself standing infront of a cave.
You venture into the cave to find a large door blocking
your path.
(insert key, turn around''')
    response = input("Enter a command: ")
    while response != 'insert key' or response != 'turn around':
        if response =='insert key' or response == 'turn around':
            break
        print('Choose one of the options: ")
        response = input()
    if response == 'insert key':
        if key == 1:
              win()
        else:
              print('''You don't have a key. Get One!!''')
    elif response == 'turn around' :
        home()
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately you haven't formatted the code quite right, so we can't tell how it is indented. Please check out the faq for more details. Please also post the error message.

Comment: The presented code isn't even valid Python and will result in 'EOL while scanning string literal'! That makes this close easy - make sure to submit a *valid* and *representative* test-case. (And when said issue is fixed, there are [no indent errors](http://ideone.com/SpGLQ3) with the code.)

Comment: Mixing spaces and tabs might cause this.

Answer (score 7):

That's almost *always* caused by mixing tabs and spaces. Check your file contents with an editor that can show you this, such as by using `:set list` in `vi`.

But you may also want to look at this line:

```
print('Choose one of the options: ")
```

You're starting your string with one quote type and ending it with another, which is valid is neither Python 2 *nor* 3.

Once I'd fixed that and ensured that indentation was correct, it worked fine for me. I had to add a mainline that called `cave()` but it ran without error albeit not doing much useful since I don't have any of the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notepade+ or VIM then check where is the tabs and space.

Also make sure that string you started must be end with same character. If you start with `'`(Single quote) then end with same.

```
print('Choose one of the options: ")
```

Ablove line start with `'` but end with `"`. That will give you syntext error.

Answer (score 0):

The indent block may cause by when you paste the code, before the code is 4 blanks (not in ascii), the python cannot read it , you can delete it and add a 'tab'.